# Kernel source code for ubuntu 3.19.0 version

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

My system is of ubuntu 3.19.0-25-generic kernel version and need to work on kernel level for some application so how can access to the source code for that version and only headers are present in /usr/src/ folder but couldn't able to find source code.How do i get t?

Comment: You should explain (so **edit your question** please) what kind of *application* are you working on. Usually, they don't need any kernel source code

Comment: $ apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r) it is getting downloaded with 3.13.0 version.why is that so?

Comment: How can we know? We don't know your system and how it was configured? Did you `apt-get update`?.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 aptitude search 'linux*3.19*'
```

you might have some `-source` package.

Otherwise, add some `deb-src` source line into your `/etc/apt/sources.list` (similar to a `deb` line, but replace the first `deb` with `deb-src`).

Alternatively, fetch a recent kernel source from http://kernel.org/ and compile it into a `*.dpkg` package (using `make-kpkg` or equivalent)

BTW, you might not need the entire kernel source to compile some [kernel module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadable_kernel_module). AFAIK the `linux*-kbuild` and `linux*-headers` packages should be enough.

Comment: I have downloaded source code of the currently using kernel and i have put some breakpoints in pid.c code then what should i need to compile only pid.c code? printk(KERN_DEBUG "message\n"); as my breakpoint